# How to deploy a Jython app on Heroku

Tags: heroku, flask, jython

Is it possible to deploy a Jython app, which uses Flask, on Heroku? There is very little info on this, and according to this article it should be possible by adding a pom.xml: http://venturebeat.com/2011/08/26/heroku-java/. I know Heroku supports JRuby natively, but there's nothing on Jython.

I have an app that references a .jar library, from within Jython. When trying to push the local git repo to Heroku a Python app is detected, packages in requirements.txt file are installed and deploy completes. Unfortunately, when accessing the app online, I get an Application error (Note: gunicorn package has been installed to project and added to requirements.txt). The Log states the following:[image: Heroku Error when loading app.]

Comment: Why _wouldn't_ it work? Isn't Jython fundamentally just another Java library? Have you tried it?

Comment: @Chris, precisely my thoughts; nonetheless, Heroku is detecting a Python app when I deploy the app. So my guess is that Heroku only supports native Java, Scala, JRuby and Clojure.

Comment: What role does `requirements.txt` play in Jython? (I understand its role in regular Python projects; for some reason I would have expected Jython to use Maven for dependency management.) When Heroku sees `requirements.txt` in the root of your repository it builds your code as a Python (CPython or PyPy) project. I expect you need Heroku to build your code as a _Java_ project.